# Table not created by Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I annotated a bunch of POJO's so JPA can use them to create tables in Hibernate.  It appears that all of the tables are created except one very central table called "Revision".  The Revision class has an `@Entity(name="RevisionT")` annotation so it will be renamed to RevisionT so there is not a conflict with any reserved words in MySQL (the target database).

I delete the entire database, recreate it and basically open and close a JPA session.  All the tables seem to get recreated without a problem.

Why would a single table be missing from the created schema?  What instrumentation can be used to see what Hibernate is producing and which errors?

Thanks.

UPDATE:  I tried to create as a Derby DB and it was successful.  However, one of the fields has a a name of "index".  I use `@org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn` to specify the name to something other than a reserved word.  However, the column is always called "index" when it is created.

Here's a sample of the suspect annotations.

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MasterTopID")
    @IndexColumn(name="Cx3tHApe")
    protected MasterTop masterTop;
```

Instead of creating `MasterTop.Cx3tHApe` as a field, it creates `MasterTop.Index`.  Why is the name ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to your side question (What instrumentation can be used to see what Hibernate is producing and which errors?)

You can `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` to generate your tables.

```
AnnotationConfiguration conf = (new AnnotationConfiguration()).configure();
new SchemaExport(conf).create(showHql, run);
```

The first argument allows you to see which HQL this command generates (`CREATE TABLE`s etc). The second one is whether it should actually perform any modifications (ie false = dry-run).

So running it with `(true, false)` will show you exactly what Hibernate would do to your tables, without changing anything.

Comment: That helped enormously!  I discovered that there was still an column called "Index" being created.  Further investigation showed the @OneToMany side of the schema also had @IndexColumn(name="Index").  Hibernate ignored the @IndexColumn on the @ManyToOne.  I'm still wondering why there's no output from Hibernate.  Oh well.  It works!

Answer (score 7):

In case this helps anybody, this happened to me today and it turned out I was using a reserved word on my entity definition:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="list")
@OrderColumn(name="order")
private List<Wish> wishes;
```

"order" in this case, and Hibernate just skipped over this class. So check your user defined names! :)

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

[name attribute](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) on `@Entity` is not what you want to use for this purpose. Use `@Table` annotation instead:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RevisionT")
public class Revision {
```

Comment: Good idea.  It didn't help. :(

Answer (score 1):

It is due to column names matches with your sql reserved words. You can try by changing name of columns. I had faced similar type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a syntax mistake in **columnDefinition**. Easily detectable by the debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using the wrong annotation. Once I accidentally annotated an entity with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` instead of `@javax.persistence.Entity`, and Hibernate just skipped it.

Comment: I am using @javax.persistence.Entity.  However, I do have a org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn.  Could mixing annotations cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put hibernate.show_sql config property to true and see if Hibernate generated the create table code. If so, copy the create statement into your database client (ui or command line) and see if your database returns an error.

For me the error was not apparent until I did so.

I used the field name 'condition' which was a reserved MySQL word.
So check your field names...