# Auto Generating Hibernate Entities

Tags: hibernate

I have a pretty complex database schema and would like to know if there are any tools which I can use to auto-generate the entities if I am using Hibernate as my persistence mechanism.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for database "schema generation" (ie automatically create your tables with PKs etc), try `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport`, as I said [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376543/table-not-created-by-hibernate/1379976#1379976).

Use it like this:

```
AnnotationConfiguration conf = (new AnnotationConfiguration()).configure();
new SchemaExport(conf).create(showHql, run);
```

(check the link above for more info)

However, if you're looking for auto-generation of Hibernate mapping files (**.hbm.xml*) or annotations, you should look into [Hibernate Tools](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html), as stated below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from one of my build files:

```
<taskdef name="hibernatetool" 
         classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" 
         classpathref="toolslib" />

...

<target name="generate-ddl-script" depends="build">
    <hibernatetool>
        <annotationconfiguration configurationfile="${hibernate.cfg}" />
        <hbm2ddl export="false"
                 update="false"
                 drop="true"
                 create="true"
                 destdir="${scripts.dir}"
                 outputfilename="create-tables.ddl" />
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```